# ASP Cache Control and ETags without access to server

Tags: caching, asp-classic, cache-control, google-pagespeed, etags

I'm looking to optimize my ASP pages. Google best practices tell me to set expiration dates, modification dates and ETags etc.

I get the logic of it all, but I don't understand the details of the implementation and since we're using ASP pages, it's very hard to find the information and I don't have access to change anything directly on the server.

Would this be the type of info I would be looking to configure? And with what?

```
<%
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
Response.Expires = -1
%>
```

And how do ETags work? Do I just decide on a number for the url or does there have to be some logic?

Most of the pages on our site have content that only changes 1 or 2 a year and then image files that sometimes change daily or weekly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't forget to return status `304 Not Modified` when you detect a cache hit.

ie. Etags, you would need to generate a unique id for the bit of content/page first, then return it as a header.  Then the browser will add that request header next time it try's to fetch it, but if you don't return the right status when you see the request header, then it's not implemented completely.

In this case you can do something like this:

```
eTag = "t153120141610"

If eTag = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ETAG") Then
  Response.Status = "304 Not Modified"
  Response.End
End If

Response.AddHeader "etag",eTag

Response.Write "Cache me next time via eTag: " & eTag
```

Just make sure you're generating a unique id, because it's easy to return content of entirely something else that's already stored in the clients browser with the same eTag.  Good luck.

---

### Edit:

A common way of making a self-signed eTag, would be to first identify all the types of content that will be cached (ie: Forum Page, Post Page, Profile Page) and usually there is an Id to each one of these. Then encode it using md5 or base64.
So you can do something like this if you wanted to keep it in the clients browser for 1 day.

Profile Page:

```
eTag = Base64Encode("Profile" & ProfileId & Date)
```

This means the eTag will change every day, therefore, it will be cached for 1 day, then the following day a new eTag will be generated and the old eTag won't be recognizable anymore. You can also have a `last modified date` field in a database or file and use that instead of Date, so it only changes when the content changes.

(NOTE: I don't use etags, I use `Last-modified` and `If-Modified-Since` headers instead for browser-side caching, for the obvious reasons.)

Comment: Thanks, that seems pretty straight forward. I have another question how do associate that ETag with a specific file? And do I need to change eTag in the header ecah time I modify a page? Basically I don't fully understand what I have to update each time I modify a file